# Partition table errors when trying to unstall Ubuntu LTS 20.04 beside windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, partition-table

I have done partitions and freed up over 100 free space in hard disk. I used Rufus for the bootable Pendrive in boot manager.

When I try to install Ubuntu it loads 100%, but then it just keep loading. I left it for hours, but don't know why these errors are showing:

```
the backup gpt table is corrupt, but  the primary appears ok .
chroot:can't execute 'debconf-communicate':input/output error.
failed unmounting /cdrom
dependency failed for SSSD Autofs service responder socket.
dependency failed for SSSD NSS service responder socket.
dependency failed for SSSD PAC service responder socket.
dependency failed for SSSD PAM service responder socket.
dependency failed for SSSD Sudo service responder socket.
```

Comment: Windows in UEFI boot mode requires gpt partitioning. What tool did you use to resize Windows? And have you rebooted Windows as it needs to run chkdsk after any resize. Post this above in your question: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` if drive is sda or change to correct drive if not sda. What brand/model system?

Comment: I've used  windows disk management for shrinking the disk ,yes i've rebooted multiple times after shrinking ,I'm using acer aspire 3 64bit

Comment: Be sure to update UEFI firmware & SSD firmware. Turn off Intel RST/RAID and use AHCI. Similar but 5 model: Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167506/the-installation-window-dont-show-a-root-file-system-for-choose-in-the-installa

Comment: thank you ,it worked ,after i changed to AHCI from Raid in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Acer & many other systems need UEFI setting for drives changed from Intel RST/RAID to AHCI. If dual booting with Windows install AHCI drivers into Windows first.

Also many need UEFI & SSD firmware updates.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems

But if you do a safe boot first to update Windows, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works

https://superuser.com/questions/1672500/ubuntu-installation-with-intel-rst?noredirect=1#comment2565531_1672500

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/

Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial

Acer Aspire A515-54G Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211911/cannot-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-a515-54g-laptop-hard-drive-not-detected
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702